# PHP file write permission

Tags: apache-2.2, php, permissions

I have two files, one php file and one log file. The permission has been changed to the following:

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 www-data www-data  294 2012-06-25 10:17 function.php

-rwxr-x--- 1 www-data www-data    0 2012-06-25 09:53 log.txt
```

The permission is set to 750.

when I call function.php, I receive the following error message

```
fopen(log.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

This is the line :

```
$fp = fopen("log.txt","a");
```

I am very confused. I have php and the file to be written both under www-data now, so why would there be any permission problem?

Please help

Comment: System log says...?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't on Windows, you can check if your process is really own by www-data by

```
$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
print $processUser['name'];
```

Check the directory too ! Are you sure that you are in the right dir ?

```
echo getcwd();
```